# Using complex fourier series when calculating maximum square error.

Tags: fourier-series

when calculating the maximum square error I have this formula
$$E^* = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f^2 dx - \pi \left[ 2a_0^2 + \sum_{n = 1}^N (a_n^2 + b_n^2) \right ]$$
But I was wondering, if I have  a complex fourier series, can I just exchange $a_n$ & $b_n$ with $c_n$ like this
$$E^* = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f^2 dx - \pi \left[ 2a_0^2 + \sum_{n = 1}^N c_n^2 \right ]$$

Comment: What are $a_n,b_n,c_n$?

Comment: $a_n,b_n$ are the fourier coefficients. $c_n$ is the complex fourier coefficient.

Comment: Is there some relationship between the $a_n,b_n,c_n$??? If you set $c_n = \sqrt{a_n^2+b_n^2}$ then you can replace the $a_n,b_n$. It is really not clear what you are asking.